# error: cannot list snaps: Get https:

Tags: snap

While entering the the `snap find` command, I'm getting the below mentioned error. Kindly help me to solve it.
Linux Version: Linux ubuntu01 4.4.0-62-generic

```
$snap find
error: cannot list snaps: Get https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict%xxxxxxxxxxxxxx net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: I'm having `error: cannot search: got unexpected HTTP status code 403 via GET to (...)` in Ubuntu 20.04 and my Internet is working fine. In any case I wanted libreoffice and `$ sudo snap install libreoffice` works (I know the snap name). I waited a few minutes and `snap find` began working again.

Answer (score 2):

`snap find` queries an online catalog of software, so requires an internet connection. Please check your connection is working fine.

One quick check you can make is whether the url it prints is accessible in a browser. Try visiting `https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/search` and see if you get a response which starts with `{"_embedded": {"clickindex:package": [{"anon_download_url": "https://...`.

Comment: Thank you .. It's working fine after providing the proxy setting in environment profile.